# ./configure script should fail on enabling mistyped parameters

Tags: configure, autotools

I work with an autotools project an trying to add new features to the build system (adding new components, etc). While doing it, strangely I discovered that if I add a `bla` option to it (in `configure.ac`), but by mistake call it like:

```
$ ./configure  --with-blabla
```

It silently complains that:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-blabla
```

and the configuration process still continues. I would like to stop the process instead if an unrecognized `--with` is encountered. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'option' will have no effect. In that sense, a warning is sufficient. Matched `--with-<package>` options are enabled by a [`AC_ARG_WITH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#External-Software), so while `blabla` might be ignored now, there's no reason why `--with-blabla` or `--enable-blabla` might not be useful in the future.

More to the point: `./configure --help` gives a list of valid configure options. It's not about failing with an unrecognized option - which brings us to an important point:

Some packages are built recursively, when a package has several sub-packages, an option may not be relevant to all of them, and yet you want to pass it to the package that does accept the option. In short - I see no reason to disable this behaviour.

Of course, if you really want to, you can invoke `autoconf` with:

`autoconf --warnings=error` in generating the `configure` script.